# Mysql query to insert "EXPIRED" into wordpress titles

Tags: mysql, wordpress

On my Wordpress site I have several thousand posts of expired deals.  They are all in the Archived category.  I am looking for a Mysql query or php program that will insert the string "EXPIRED" in front of all their titles (Archived posts).    I would appreciate suggestions.
PS - There are plugins that would do this but they all require that I edit each post to set an expiration date, and I have thousands of posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET titleColumn = CONCAT('EXPIRED ', titleColumn) 
WHERE category = 'archived'
```

You have to adjust the tablename, columnnames and the where clause.

Don't forget to backup your data before changing values from outside of your program.

Fiddle before update: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74462a/3

Fiddle after update: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b27752/2

Comment: I created a new category called test and then ran this exact query: UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_title = CONCAT('EXPIRED ', post_title) 
WHERE post_category = 'test'                    I do not understand why, but all the posts were updated.

Comment: Well, that should not be possible. Added fiddle showing the result of your update statement